# Commutators of a symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I am trying to prove that the commutator subgroup of $S_n$ ($S_n$ is a symmetric group on $[n]$), $[S_n,S_n]$ consists solely of commutators $s_1^{-1}s_2^{-1}s_1s_2$ for some $s_1,s_2\in S_n$. Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a group $G$, by $[G,G]$ I mean a group *generated* by all the commutators, $\{g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1}g_1g_2:g_1,g_2\in G\}$.

Comment: Salomo, thanks, and yes, I know that $A_n=[S_n,S_n]$ for all $n\geq 5$. It seems that it is much more difficult to show that $A_n$ is not only equal to $[S_n,S_n]$, but in fact every element of it is a commutator, which is not necessarily true for $[S_n,S_n]$.

Answer (score 3):

To prove that every element in $A_n$ is a commutator, you would have to divide it into several cases and prove that each k-cycle can be written as a commutator.

G.A. Miller's paper prove the statement:
http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183416038

as well as Noboru Ito's, which I can't find online.

Hope it is helpful.